# Distribute different version of an iOS app to different clients

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, apple-developer, b2b, apple-developer-enterprise

We have an iOS app that we are currently looking forward to distributing to various clients in the live environment. We have several versions of the same app (version 4, version 5 and etc). Each client wants a different version. We need to handle multiple versioning of the app. We were searching the distribution options.

1. Ad-Hoc Distribution
2. App Store
3. In-House Distribution
4. Custom Apps

Searched various options that we need to follow in order to achieve the multiple versioning requirement but didn't find a clear answer. We were checking the Custom Apps options and had a few doubts.

1. **Will it be a problem with multiple versioning?**
2. **If we need to submit an app with a different version do we need to submit it as a new app?**

We would be grateful if someone give a clear thought about how do we need to handle this multiple versioning thing in the same app.

Please note that the app name and logo will be the same in every version.

Comment: You would need to submit separate apps with different bundle ids for the different versions.

Comment: @Paulw11 - Will it be problem in apple review process for custom apps? Because even if change the bundle ids it's still the same app name and logo.

Comment: You get much more leeway with app review for custom apps.  I wouldn't expect you would have a problem since the apps will be for different customers.